# How do you create a 3D Model to be uploaded and viewed by HTC Vive

Tags: modeling

Needing to create some 3D models, how can they be uploaded to the HTC Vive to be viewed on VR. DO i need to use another program such as, Unity, and or Unreal, or Steam. How would i create the model VR ready.
Thanks

Comment: VR ready = game ready. Make a game model (there are plenty of tutorials). As far as viewing on the HTC Vive, I believe unity supports that. You can use the obj or fbx formats to export from blender to unity. Blender  doesn't have direct internal support afaik.

Answer (score 0):

There is an plugin but it does not seem to have been updated in the last 4 months.

That said the video is amazing, though it is only head tracking in room-space no controllers. You can always get the source code.

https://github.com/cedeon/virtual_reality_viewport/tree/vivetest

http://uploadvr.com/blenders-open-source-software-just-got-makeshift-vr-support/